# Using multiple, named section landmarks within main - beneficial or superfluous?

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers

As a non-screenreader user, I feel like adding named sections to a page would increase ease-of-navigation as would bolster any existing heading structures. Landmarks can be quickly cycled through via keyboard by screenreader shortcuts e.g. 'd' in NVDA, providing a good summary of a page.

Example 1 shows a [UK government page](https://www.gov.uk/) (which obviously must be highly accessible), where the main content is in a `<main>` tag containing multiple `<section>` tags containing headings and lists.
The screenshot shows an overlay showing the landmarks - one can see that the search bar has its own landmark, however subsequent sections don't (they can be navigated to by other means, of course).
If I navigate this via screen reader, it takes a long time to tab or cycle through the lists of headings (maybe there is a way to skip these that I'm unaware of?)

Example 2 shows the same site but with named regions (via aria-label) which means that each section can be navigated to using landmarks - a screenreader (NVDA for example) reads out "Topics  region    Topics  heading    level 2", which does seem superfluous but does seem to make navigation more agile or atleast being able to audit/summarise a site.

My question is whether example 2 is beneficial or, on the flipside, perhaps even detrimental to the a11y experience?

Any thoughts appreciated

*Example 1*

[image: Example 1 - no named sections]

*Example 2*

[image: Example 2 - named sections]

Comment: Down-voting without an explanation is not very constructive IMO

Comment: I think this is a very good question, mainly because I am trying to understand exactly the same thing :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 2 is better because of the additional way a screen reader can navigate (by landmark). There is no drawback to example 2 unless there are so many <section> elements that it defeats the purpose of having just a "handful" of landmarks to make it quick to jump to part of the page.

I'm surprised the <section> elements don't have an `aria-label`.  Without the label, the <section> is not considered a landmark.

https://w3c.github.io/html-aria/#el-section

> **HTML element:** <section>
>
> role=region *if the section element has an accessible name*
>
> Otherwise, role=generic

Why go to the trouble of having a <section> if the user can't benefit from it?

> If I navigate this via screen reader, it takes a long time to tab or cycle through the lists of headings (maybe there is a way to skip these that I'm unaware of?)

There are lots of <h3> elements and if you are navigating using the <kbd>H</kbd> key, then yes it'll take a while to go through all the headings (h1, h2, h3, h4, etc).  However, you can also navigate by specific heading levels using <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, etc.  So if you want to skip over all the <h3> elements, you can navigate with <kbd>2</kbd> to quickly jump to each <h2> before all the <h3>'s.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware of using the specific heading levels. Using '2' to jump to <h2> does make it much quicker to navigate the example site. That said, I'm surprised that section landmarks/regions aren't used more often to group related content.